# C# how to limit numerical input to a single digit

Tags: c#, integer, digit

sorry that this is probably easy im new to C# and i need to limit the inputs here to a single digit.

```
 int value, value1, value2, value3, value4;
 int resultFinal, resultFirst, resultSecond, resultThird = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter five single digit numbers");

        value = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        value1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());            
        value2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        value3 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        value4 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());


        resultFirst = value - value1;
        resultSecond = value2 - value3;      
        resultThird = resultFirst + resultSecond;
        resultFinal = resultThird + value4;
        Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", resultFinal);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any button to close");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You can't limit the returned string by `Console.ReadLine()`. You should write code to check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter five single digit numbers");
List<int> list = new List<int>();
do
{
    var keyNumber = (int)Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
    if (keyNumber >= 48 && keyNumber <= 57)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your input number is:" + (char)keyNumber);
        list.Add(keyNumber-48);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but please enter single digit numbers!");
    }
}
while (list.Count < 5);
var resultFirst = list[0] - list[1];
var resultSecond = list[2] - list[3];
var resultThird = resultFirst + resultSecond;
var resultFinal = resultThird + list[4];
Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", resultFinal);
Console.WriteLine("Press any button to close");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Because you just want user to enter singele digit number,I think `Console.ReadKey(true)` is more better